# Discord.py Как я могу проверить содержимое сообщения?

Tags: python, discord.py

**Я, с помощью discord.py, хочу сделать текстовый канал в своей гильдии, где будут одни картинки и ничего лишнего.** Т.к. у меня не достаточно знаний в языке - прошу помощи! Так вот, как я могу проверять сообщение пользователя и если там будет текст - его удалять?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import config
import asyncio
from asyncio import sleep
from discord import utils
import random

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix =".", intents = discord.Intents.all())
client.remove_command("help")
only_pictures_channel_id = 853722060499845141
#Сообщение о том, что бот запущен.
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот запущен")
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send("Бот запущен")
@client.event
async def om_command_error(ctx, error):
    pass
#.hello
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(f"{author.mention}, привет. Кст, а ты знал, что я руиню жизнь своему создателю? ^..^")
#.clear
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def clear(ctx, amount: int):
    amount = int(amount)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount+1)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = "Чат был очищен", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, delete_after=10)
#.kikc
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member,*,reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, был кикнут, т.к. нёс херню.", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send(f"{member.name} - был кикнут!")
#.ban
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member,*,reason=None):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, допизделся и был сослан в Dungeon навсегда по причине: *{reason}*.", color = discord.Color.purple())
    emb.set_thumbnail(url = "https://pics.me.me/thumb_deep-dark-fantasy-youtube-49022628.png")
    await ctx.send(embed = emb)
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send(f"{member.name} - был забанен!")
#.help
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    emb = discord.Embed(title = "Навигация по командам сервера", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    emb.set_author(name = client.user.name, icon_url = client.user.avatar_url)
    emb.add_field(name = "Команда *.hello* используется для вписания в хату.",value = ".hello")
    emb.add_field(name = "Команда *.clear* используется для очистки чата (Только для администраторов).",value = ".clear")
    emb.add_field(name = "Команда *.kick* - отвечает за гонения пользователя с сервера (Только для администраторов).",value = ".kick")
    emb.add_field(name = "Команда *.ban* - отвечает за запрет доступа пользователю к серверу (Только для администраторов).",value = ".ban")
    await ctx.send(embed=emb, delete_after=120)
#.TMute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mute_members = True)
async def tmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    TMute = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "TMute")
    await member.add_roles(TMute)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, потерял доступ к текстовому чату. D:", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
    await asyncio.sleep(600)
    await member.remove_roles(TMute)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, был прощён и преобрёл доступ к текстовому чату. :D", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send(f"{member.name} - получил мут текстового чата!")
#.VMute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(mute_members = True)
async def vmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    VMute = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "VMute")
    await member.add_roles(VMute)
    await member.move_to(None)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, потерял доступ к голосовому чату. D:", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
    await asyncio.sleep(600)
    await member.remove_roles(VMute)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, был прощён и преобрёл доступ к голосовому чату. <3", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send(f"{member.name} - получил мут голосового чата!")
#.TunMute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def tunmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    TMute = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "TMute")
    await member.remove_roles(TMute)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, был прощён и преобрёл доступ к текстовому чату. :D", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
#.VunMute
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def vunmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    VMute = discord.utils.get(ctx.message.guild.roles, name = "VMute")
    await member.remove_roles(VMute)
    emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, был прощён и преобрёл доступ к голосовому чату. :D", colour = discord.Color.purple())
    await ctx.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
#Выдача роли
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(850994154438787072)
    value = random.randint(1,3)
    if value == 1:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 853266138380632075)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, присоеденился и был распределён в команду розовых!", colour = discord.Color.pink())
    elif value == 2:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 853266791256817684)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, присоеденился и был распределён в команду синих!", colour = discord.Color.blu())
    elif value == 3:
        role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = 853368542787534858)
        await member.add_roles(role)
        emb = discord.Embed(title = f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, присоеденился и был распределён в команду красных!", colour = discord.Color.red())
    await channel.send(embed = emb, delete_after=60)
    await client.get_user(363678879061377024).send(f"Пользователь, под именем {member.name}, присоеденился к гильдии!")
#Канал с пикчами
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.channel.id == only_pictures_channel_id:
        if len(message.attachments) > 0 and message.content == '':
            if message.attachments[0].url.split('.')[-1].lower() not in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg']:
                await message.delete()
        else:
            await message.delete()
#ошибки
@clear.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.name}, обязательно укажите аргумент!", delete_after=15)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("У вас недостаточно прав!", delete_after=15)
    elif isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await ctx.send("Такой команды не существует!", delete_after=15)
#Запуск
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Создадим объект бота, который будет управлять сообщениями:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

**Создадим функцию обработки всех полученных сообщений:**

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
```

Дальше мы будем работать с объектом сообщения `message`, полученным в виде аргумента функции. Из объекта сообщения вы можете получить `автора`, `канал`, `сервер` и [**много чего еще**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message).

**Внутри функции, первым делом пропишем игнорирование сообщений от ботов:**

```
if message.author.bot: return
```

**Затем, проверим в какой канал пришло сообщение. Мы работаем с сообщениями только определенного канала.** Добавим в функцию условие проверки по `id`:

```
only_pictures_channel_id = 920573476320590836 # здесь, вместо этого id вставьте id
                                              # вашего канала с картинками
if message.channel.id == only_pictures_channel_id:
```

---

Теперь, когда у нас есть функция проверки сообщений, и прописаны все необходимые условия, можем начать отбор "правильных" сообщений.

**Из объекта `message` получаем текст сообщения: `message.content`**

**А также список (`list`) его вложений: `message.attachments`**

*В списке вложений могут быть не только изображения, но и звуковые, текстовые и прочие файлы. Нам нужно отсеять их.*

**Нам подходят условия, когда нет текста, то есть `message.content == ''` и когда количество вложений не равно нулю, то есть `len(message.attachments) > 0`**. Если оба условия совпадают, то проверяем, чтобы расширение файла соответствовало расширению изображения:

```
if len(message.attachments) > 0 and message.content == '':
    if message.attachments[0].url.split('.')[-1].lower() not in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg']:
        await message.delete()
else:
    await message.delete()
```

**Таким образом, если не совпадает расширение или начальные условия, сообщение будет удалено.**

---

**Полный код:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents = discord.Intents.all())

only_pictures_channel_id = 920573476320590836

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot: return
    if message.channel.id == only_pictures_channel_id:
        if len(message.attachments) > 0 and message.content == '':
            if message.attachments[0].url.split('.')[-1].lower() not in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif', 'jpeg']:
                await message.delete()
        else:
            await message.delete()

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

### Не забудьте указать токен, а также выдать боту права на "Управление сообщениями" на сервере

---

Подробнее о проверке расширения:

```
message.attachments[0].url.split('.')[-1].lower()
```

Здесь мы получаем объект вложения, из которого можем получить ссылку на него, через `url`. Затем, полученную ссылку мы разбиваем на 2 части по символу "**.**" (точка), и забираем последний (`[-1]`) элемент списка, содержащий расширение файла. После чего, используя `lower()` меняем все его символы верхнего регистра на нижний, чтобы было меньше условия для проверки.

Comment: Спасибо за полный код и за грамотный ответ, очень помогли!

Comment: Ещё один вопрос: Бот зависает на этом действии, он удаляет сообщения исправно, но команды которые идут перед строчками и после - не руботают.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду то, что бот не выполняет другие свои команды? Для этого добавьте в начало функции `async def on_message()` вот такую строку: `await bot.process_commands(message)`

Comment: Опять столкнулся с проблемой, пробую код запустить отдельно - работает, а пробую его интегрировать в свой код - он не выдавая ошибки - ничего не удаляет.

Comment: Дополните ваш вопрос именно нерабочей версией кода

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос

Comment: Вы зачем-то в коде объявили двух ботов - `bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".", intents = discord.Intents.all())` и `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix =".", intents = discord.Intents.all())`. А запускаете в конце только `client`. Оставьте какого-то одного, запускайте только его и все декораторы типа`@bot.command()` и `@bot.event`  поменяйте на `@client.command`/`@client.event` или наоборот

Comment: Если проще, удалите 9 сточку (`bot = ...`) и в функции `on_message` замените декоратор `@bot.event` на `@client.event`

Comment: Так и знал что в этом ошибка, но не мог найти какая, спасибо!